# how to use \hspace in beamer frametitle

Tags: latex, beamer

I would like to adjust my title some mm to the right, but when I try this:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\hspace{5mm}}
```

my title just gets shifted downwards. I don't understand why:
[image]

I've also tried to use this:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\hspace{4mm}\insertframetitle}
```

but then my whole title is per default shifted a huge amount to the right:

[image: second approach]

Comment: I am so sorry, I meant to ask this on tex.stackexchange. Is there a way to transfer this, or do I just delete?

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to move your question there? Compare the steadily increasing number of unanswered  beamer questions there with the answer rate here.

Comment: (in your second approach you basically just overwrite the definition of the `frametitle` template, thus undoing all the setting to change the margins, the horizontal spacing etc.) With such a definition you will no longer be able to control things like the size or insert a subtitle and more importantly: the body text in your frame will jump around depending on which letters you have in your frametitle, e.g. descenders.

Comment: I already assumed that, but wanted to try anyway ':)
thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to append space at the begin of the `frametitle` template won't work because the `frametitle` is normally set in a `beamercolorbox` which spans the whole page. If you add space in front of it, it will no longer fit in the line and thus latex will add a line break before it. Best approach would be to redefine the template to make the box smaller.

Assuming you use the default `frametitle` template (adjust the position by changing the line I marked with `<- change value here`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by-4cm% <- change value here
  \hfill%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fteleft\endcsname\fi%
    \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\strut\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: @eli44 You're welcome!